# Why angular acceleration of objects that are part of a composite body must be equal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, rotation

[image]

[image: Description]

In the problem above why is the angular acceleration (and other quantities describing motion like angular velocity) constant for the composite body? If the bar rotates counterclockwise as it is pushed forwards, then the disk must rotate clockwise while the displacements of the contact points of the bar and disk with the ground are equal. As a result, it does not seem clear that any line connecting two points on the body have an equal angular acceleration and velocity since the direction could differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in dynamics, we always want to simplify many rigid bodies, to a composite system to make calculation and rigid body motion easier to visualize
as in your question you are not trying to see it as composite system, if you treat bar and 
 disk as separate system the dynamic motion would become very complex to be calculable

as for your 1st question--

*In the problem above why is the angular acceleration (and other quantities describing motion like angular velocity) constant for the composite body?*

as I have said combine the the two bodies as system, then you could find the center of mass of combined bodies in similar way you find COM of 2 particles (it holds for every situation but when required, it is extensively used in rotataional dynamics), hence you could also find acceleration of COM by treating rod and disk as 2 particles using COM concept. hence acceleration of 2 bodies may be different but we can always have acceleration of system
$M(asys)$  $=$ $\cfrac{ma1 + ma2}{m+m}$ $=$ $Fsys$ $\space$   ($Fsys$  is force on the whole system)

as force, hence torque is constant so acceleration of whole system $asys$ is constant and angular acceleration is constant as well because both objects would be rotating about a constant instantaneous axis , I will answer more briefly below--

your 2nd question

*If the bar rotates counterclockwise as it is pushed forwards, then the disk must rotate clockwise while the displacements of the contact points of the bar and disk with the ground are equal.As a result, it does not seem clear that any line connecting two points on the body have an equal angular acceleration and velocity since the direction could differ.*

treat it as combine system, in rotational dynamics we could find the combined moment of inertia of objects about axis of rotation, by using instantaneous axis of rotation ,
you could draw lines from velocity of C and B that are perpendicular to their velocity (of ends B and C), B point velocity would intersect center of disk as the velocity would be tangential, C point velocity intersects center of disk Note:- velocity is vector so you could extend the vector velocity(only its unit vector) to the bottom of disk, extend perpendicular from it you will see it intersects center of disk, hence you could find moment of inertia about this point(center of disk) of system , and equate it with torque and get angular acceleration of system about center of disk it would make your problem solving skills much sharper.

**the rod and disk would rotate about center of disk(instantaneous axis) and as both rod and disk rotate about common axis hence they would have common acceleration hence whole composite system has same angular velocity**

do not overthink about angular momentum/velocity would be in which direction, we always 
use COM concept to derive these quantities of complex system (by differentiating COM basic formula you can get acceleration /velocity, which would have been complicated to derive by treating them as different objects)----same notion goes for moment of inertia, you could find moment of inertia of complex system imagining them like you are deriving MOI(moment of inertia) of point patricles about a axis, however MOI of objects would not be  equal to $MR^2$ like of point particles, it can be of rod or disk or anything about an axis and then take summation of them..